# LangChain RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter ONLY by character (ignoring chunk size)

Tags: terraform, langchain

I have a bunch of terraform files, and I want to load them in LangChain and split them by RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter, but I would like to ignore the chunk size and ONLY use the separators. For example. Let's say I have this tf file:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("<YOUR_CREDENTIALS_JSON>")
  project     = "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>"
  region      = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  name     = "my-bucket-name"
  location = "US"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "my-cloudrun-service"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project}/my-image:latest"
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "public" {
  service  = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  location = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}

output "cloud_run_url" {
  value = "${google_cloud_run_service.default.status[0].url}"
}

output "bucket_url" {
  value = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.my_bucket.name}/"
}
```

And what I want is creating three documents, one with the provider, one with one resource and one with the other resource. Once I load the document, it would make sense to use something like:

```
terraform_separators=[
                # First, try to split along definitions
                "\n\nresource ",
                "\n\nmodule ",
                "\n\ndata ",
                "\n\nlocals ",
                "\n\nvariable "
                "\n\noutput ",
                "\nresource ",
                "\nmodule ",
                "\ndata ",
                "\nlocals ",
                "\nvariable ",
                "\noutput ",
                # Now split by the normal type of lines
                "\n\n",
                "\n",
                " ",
                "",
            ]

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(separators=terraform_separators, chunk_size=300, chunk_overlap=0)
```

The problem is that the chunk_size has more importance than the separator itself, is there a way to give more importance to the separator only?

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from the base class RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter and override method to implement you custom logic

```
 class CustomClass(RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter):
     def split_text(self, text: str) -> List[str]:
         pass #Your custom login
```